# How to implement the Promise Object?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I am trying to port an existing application in to Play framework. The application uses a library to do SMPP transmission which is already implemented in such a way that the messages are sent on a asynchronous fashion (in a separate thread which invokes a listener object on successful transmission). I am wondering how to use the same library and return a Promise object which returns the result to Play's web request when the listener in is updated.

All the examples I have seen illustrate how it is done using play WS library or akka, which takes care of doing the  work on a separate thread. If I already have such an implementation which does this as I explained above, how do I just integrate it with Play?

Answer (score 2):

Your SMPP transmission library gives you back a handle on which you can register completion listeners, correct? In that case you should be able to create a bridge like this:

```scala
val p = scala.concurrent.Promise[ResultType]()
val handle = smpp.doit() // or whatever the method is called
handle.onComplete(h => p.success(h.result)) // or p.complete if things can fail
return p.future
```

Then the resulting Future can be used to complete an Async Play action.